# Set value to UIPickerView row error iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

When i click the button, `pickerview` coming up and i am choosing a city from there. And if i click again i want to get what i selected before.

Here is my code,

```
-(void)cityButtonPressed{

actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 0, 0);
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
NSLog(@"selectedPickerView = %i",selectedPickerView);
[pickerView selectRow:selectedPickerView inComponent:0 animated:NO];// this line is not working
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

NSString *done = @"Done";

closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:done]];
closeButton.momentary = YES;
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 10, 50.0f, 30.0f);
closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
// Handle the selection
[cityButton setTitle:[cities objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
if (row == 0) {

    [cityButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}else{

    [cityButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

selectedPickerView = row;

}
```

What am i doing wrong here.

And one more question. When i click the button,this error is coming.

```
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

I am wondering, is it not working because of this error?

Comment: What is `selectedPickerView`? I don't see where that variable is coming from.

Comment: selectedPickerView is integer variable. I defined in implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an action sheet with no title or buttons? Ugh. Then you're adding a segmented control as a tappable button? Double ugh Apple will likely reject an app that uses a segmented control as a button.

As to your specific problem, I'm not sure if you can change the selected component in a picker view before it's on-screen. What happens if you move your selectRow:inComponent:animated: call down to after displaying the action sheet? You should probably also get rid of the reload call on your picker view, since it will load it's data when it's displayed.

Comment: Yeah it worked,i moved the selectRow:inComponent:animated: bottom of the code. Should i use normal button instead of segmented control?

Comment: i found this solution for normal button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613009/uipickerview-with-done-button Thanks a lot for your answer and advice.

Comment: Yes, you should use a normal button, not a segmented control. I would call what you posted an ABUSE of a segmented control.