# Custom buttons on UIPickerView are in disable state

Tags: ios6, uipickerview, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

i have added custom "Done" and "Cancel" button on PickerView like:

```
- (void)customBtnsToPickerView
{
    UIToolbar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelActionOfPickerView:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneActionOfPickerView:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithArray:barItems]];
    [self.pickerView addSubview:toolBar];
}
```

But they are always in disable state. i don't know what's issue inside.
i am using iphone 5 with IOS 6.1...

[image: Here is picture with disabled buttons]

Comment: From the look of your screenshot the toolbar is actually overlapping the picker. The December row is missing? Have a look at this on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613009/uipickerview-with-done-button)

Comment: No its not overlapping.

Comment: Really? where is the top of the picker frame?

Comment: <UIToolbar: 0xc2b4250; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x12b1d620>>
(lldb) po self.pickerView
<UIDatePicker: 0x12897810; frame = (0 332; 320 216); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x128978d0>>
Whats the solution here?

Comment: as per my first comment there appear to be a number of possible answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613009/uipickerview-with-done-button HTH

Comment: Just tell me whats wrong in my method..? i have added frames for Picker view and Tool bar..Don't ask me to go some where else as i have already tried all links.